# Which python module is handy for simple 2-dimension graphic demonstration task?

Tags: python, graphics

I've write a `robot pick rubbish` program.

In which the robot movement track is a list of tuples like:

```
[(0, 0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (0,2) ... ]
```

And the map is a dict with 10*10 elements like:

```
{
 (0,0): 0,
 (0,1): 1,
 (1,1): 0,
 (1,2): 0,
  ...
}
```

> the key of the map is the map coordinate, and the value indicates whether there are rubbish or not.

What I need to do, is to make a graphic 10*10 map with the `map_dict`,
and the robot moves on it with its `movement track list`.

But I have no idea what kind of module is handy for doing that job.
So meanwhile reading the tutorial of `Tkinter`, I went here for some advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [pygame](http://pygame.org) for that. Just google for some tutorials, there are many good ones out there.

Comment: Sounds a nice choice.

Comment: I've found the download page on its official site. But is it able to install `pygame` with `pip`? I tried `pip install pygame` but failed.

Comment: I needed to give full path for it to install for me something like c:\python34\scripts\pip install c:\location\of\the\pygame-version.whl